# how to rewrite a link with specific string in apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a bilingual drupal site. the languages are en and ar.
the management decide to stop ar for sometime
now i need to make a rewrite rule to redirect any user when he browses ar page to its corresponding en page

```
for example
http://mysite.com/ar/pageName
shall be redirected to
http://mysite.com/en/pageName
Note: this is the structure of links in my website
```

I have tried this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ar
RewriteRule .* en/$1 [R=302]
```

it works fine if i remove `[R=302]` but i need it as i am going to re-activate this language later and i dont wat to affect my SEO.

Thanks for your help

Comment: question has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by this rewirte rule

```
RewriteRule ^ar/(.*)[/]*        en/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ar/(.*) http://domain.com/en/$1 [R=302]
```

Put your .htaccess in the parent directory where you have both en and ar folder.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Have a look here: http://www.francescoruvolo.it/test/ar/index.html. It's working flawlessy from me. What didn't work for you? Where did you put .htaccess? Can you provide your directory tree?